# Postman - Option to view compressed response size..?

Tags: spring, rest, postman

While testing Spring GZIP compression on REST endpoint observed, with or without compression enabled postman response size showed original response size.

[image: Compression Enabled]

[image: Compression Disabled]

Content-encoding still showed as gzip, but the response size in postman is always uncompressed/original response size. This made me wonder is response compressed or not. Only after checking in chrome realised, Postman always showed uncompressed response size.

[image: Compression Enabled]
[image: Compression Disabled]

Wanted to know why postman always shows uncompressed/original response size..? Is there a option to view compressed response size in Postman..? or Is postman not the right tool to measure response size..?

Comment: Upvote, because I also want that, but actually I should downvote, because stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask for a feature, I suggest you post this at Postman under "feature request".

Comment: @Wilt, my question was to know if there is already an option to view compressed response size. I understand there is no option, as suggested I have created a "feature request" - https://community.getpostman.com/t/option-to-view-compressed-response-size/4463

Answer (score 4):

Instead of wasting time on Postman, I found [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is the easiest way to read network size

Postman is actually using Jquery-style stuff to POST/GET/PUSH... data, then show result somehow. and the `Network` tab is not always working well. In my case, it never shows once how much data was transferred back, same in my teammates' environments.

[NOTE] Fiddler gives you correct `Tunnel Received` only when request-response are in different physical location of intranet/internet.

[image]

Here is same API with different [CompressionLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=netframework-4.8)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the size by curl:

```
# without encoding
curl -v -o response.json 'http://your.site'
# with gzip encoding
curl -v -o response.json.gz -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' 'http://your.site'
```

and check the file size:

```
du -sh *
```

Example output:

```
708K    response.json
96K     response.json.gz
```