# Compression is not working in spring but, it is showing Content-Encoding as gzip in the response headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, compression

I am trying to compress the response from a java spring-boot application. I referred to some tutorials and StackOverflow questions and found that I just have to add these lines

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=1
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json
```

in the **application.properties** file, so I went ahead and added those, but after adding these lines, I am getting the **Content-Encoding** as **gzip** but the size of the response is the same as before, I also double-checked the size by removing them and the only thing that was changing was the **Content-Encoding** type and the size isn't getting affected. I am using the embedded tomcat server for the API which sends the model

```
public class UpdateUserResponseModel {
    
    private String userId;

    private String email;

    private int age;

    private long aadhaar;

    private String streetName;
    
    private String city;

    private String Country; 

    private boolean citizenCheck;

    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getAadhaar() {
        return this.aadhaar;
    }

    public void setAadhaar(long aadhaar) {
        this.aadhaar = aadhaar;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return this.streetName;
    }

    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.Country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String Country) {
        this.Country = Country;
    }

    public boolean isCitizenCheck() {
        return this.citizenCheck;
    }

    public boolean getCitizenCheck() {
        return this.citizenCheck;
    }

    public void setCitizenCheck(boolean citizenCheck) {
        this.citizenCheck = citizenCheck;
    }

}
```

and my spring-boot version is 2.4.5
Am i missing some thing here?

Comment: Are you sure your answer is bigger than 1024 kb? Cause your model looks like 200-500 Bytes JSON, in the case of reasonable sizes of String fields.

Comment: Yes, i have added some random string to increase the response to about 200KB, it has no effect

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493550/postman-option-to-view-compressed-response-size) might be the issue since i am also using postman to test my api. I checked in my browser and it shows the compressed size(transfered over network) and the decompressed size(actual size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the issue when we test with postman, as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493550/postman-option-to-view-compressed-response-size), so inorder to verify, i tried with chrome and i got the compressed size(transfered over network) and also the actual size which is displayed as (resource size), along with the header "Content-Encoding" as "gzip".